# WordPress post/page pagination (page links) to go back to the first section

Tags: pages, wp-link-pages

I am using the page links: https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links as:

```
wp_link_pages(array('before'=>'',
'next_or_number'=>'next', 
'previouspagelink' => '&laquo;',
'nextpagelink'=>'&raquo;'));
```

I want to add an additional link, For eg: X, which upon clicking will take the user to the first section. Is it possible to achieve this using this function?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First section of what?

Comment: @cjbj Thanks for the reply. By first section, I mean the original post. For eg: When you click on the navigation arrow added by the above code, the page is navigated to the rest of the content and the url changes to: post_url/2/
Since, I use many <!--nextpage--> tags on the post, the url goes as: 
post_url/2/
post_url/3/
post_url/4/ and so on...
What I want is, when you click on X, it navigates back to post_url.
I hope this explains it in a better way.

Comment: That would be a static link to the first page. You don't need to include that with `wp_link_pages`, but can simply prepend it.

Comment: Is this problem still unsolved?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to add a *First page* link between *Previous page* and *Next page* links:

```
Pages: Previous page First page Next page
```

then we could use the `wp_link_pages_args`, `wp_link_pages` and `wp_link_pages_link` filters.

Here's one such example:

**Example**

First we check the `next_or_number` attribute to see if the *next* mode is active:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args', 'wpse_initialize' );

function wpse_initialize( Array $args )
{   
    // Run only once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Activate only for 'next'
    if( 'next' === $args['next_or_number'] )
        add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', 'wpse_add_first_page_link', 10, 2 );

    return $args;
}
```

If it's active then we add the following filter callback to the `wp_link_pages_link` filter:

```
function wpse_add_first_page_link( $link, $nextorprev ) 
{
    // Custom logic for the "First page" part
    if( $nextorprev <= get_query_var( 'page', 1 ) )
        $link .= sprintf(
            ' %s%s%s%s</a> ',
            _wp_link_page( 1 ),
            $r['link_before'],
            esc_html__( 'First Page', 'mydomain' ),
            $r['link_after']
        );

    return $link;
}
```

Here we use the `_wp_link_page()` function that's used within the `wp_link_pages()` function.

This should display the *First page* part.

Finally some house cleaning:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', 'wpse_finalize' );

function wpse_finalize( $html )
{    
    // Run only once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Remove our previous filter callback
    remove_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', 'wpse_add_first_page_link', 10 );

    return $html;
}
```

Hope you can adjust this to your needs.